# Entity generated string id length to 32

Tags: java, hibernate

I have preconfigured database, which I am not able to change. *Primary Key* for application is String with max length 32. 
I have hibernate entity, that is currently using `uuid2` strategy to generate application ids.  Problem is in fact, that UUID length is 36, but I need 32. How is it better for me to generate ids for Application?

Bellow is simplified version of my current entity.

```
@Entity
public class Application {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String applicationId;

    private String name;
}
```

Comment: may be you can create a method annotated with `@PrePersist` which truncate the `applicationId` to 32 chars before presisting..

Comment: As a variant. I am not strong with hibernate, that 's why I am interested in all ways to accomplish it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found solution for my problem: Just switched to strategy `uuid` instead of `uuid2`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name = "application_id")
@Size(max = 32)
private String applicationId;
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try something like this. You can create a `PrePersist` method that can modify the value before persisting.

```
@PrePersist
public void initializeUUID() {
    if (applicationId == null) {
        applicationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString().subString(0, 32);
    } else {
        applicationId = applicationId.toString().subString(0, 32);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or take out the hypens?UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "").toString().length()

Comment: not sure if the `if true` scenario is valid, can you please test that out, whether there will be a generated value during execution of a `PrePersist` method. Else you can generate a UUID using something like the code in else statement

Comment: I have a question about such hypotetical situation with generated ID, that would be already in db. Is that possible? And if so, would hibernate solve it somehow?

Comment: Simply truncating the UUID means you increase the probability of collisions.  @caburse 's idea to take out the hyphens is better.